# undefined 'div' error in Ruby script that calculates optimal wake up time using DateTime

Tags: ruby, datetime

Here is the code for the app. The exact error message is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'div' for "50":String from (irb):5:in `new'
```

What the app is trying to do is go back 90 minutes 4 separate times and display the resulting times.

```
require 'time'

puts "What time do you have to wake up? Please use  the format H:MM"
wake_time_unformatted = gets.chomp.split(":")
wake_time= DateTime.new(1,1,1,wake_time_unformatted[0],wake_time_unformatted[1])

n=0, m=3
sleep_times = Array.new(4)
while n <= 3
    while m <= 6 
        time = wake_time - Rational(m*54000/86400)
        sleep_times[n] = time
        m = m + 1
    end
    n = n + 1
end

puts sleep_times
```

Comment: Maybe convert it to a number first.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below :

```
wake_time= DateTime.new(1,1,1,wake_time_unformatted[0].to_i,wake_time_unformatted[1].to_i)
```

`wake_time_unformatted[0]` has to be `wake_time_unformatted[0].to_i` and `wake_time_unformatted[1]` has to be `wake_time_unformatted[1].to_i`.

or change `wake_time_unformatted = gets.chomp.split(":")` to `wake_time_unformatted = gets.chomp.split(":").map(&:to_i)`. Then `DateTime.new(1,1,1,wake_time_unformatted[0],wake_time_unformatted[1])` will work.

Second change : `n=0, m=3` should be `n=0 ; m=3`.

Answer (score 1):

let me see if I can explain what's happening. You're trying to pass string arguments to DateTime.new() when it's expecting integers, and that's what's causing the error in this case. This is why Arup Rakshit's suggestion to try `gets.chomp.split(":").map(&:to_i)` will work - you're mapping the strings in your array to integers.

It's always helpful to look at the Ruby documentation and see what type of arguments the new() method will accept.

You have a second error when declaring `n = 0, m =3`. This doesn't actually assign two different values to two different variables, it's assigning values in an array. That's why rewriting it as `n=0 ; m=3` works - you're separating statements with a semicolon.

Good luck with your script.

Comment: Appreciate the help, thank you! Could you also help me figure out why the output is not an array with 4 different integer times? Right now it is just a single date that does not make sense.

Comment: It actually is an array! Try changing `puts sleep_times` to `print sleep_times` and you'll see the result is an array with four values: one is a date, the rest are `nil`. This is happening because your inner loop is only running once and assigning to the first position only.